# Как инициализировать ArrayList из char array?

Tags: java, коллекции, arraylist, char

Есть такой код:

```
List<Character> charArray = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(string.toCharArray()));
```

Но происходит ошибка времени компиляции. Почему?(может из-за `Character` и `char`?) Но почему тогда с `int` все работает?

```
List<Integer> charArray = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(23,22,32));
```

UPD: Забыл добавить, не используя цикл.

Comment: Попробуй `Arrays.<Character>asList(...)`

Comment: @notaProgrammer "cannot resolve method aslist with a char[]"

Comment: @АнтонСорокин что за `Arrays.asList()`?

Comment: @AGS17 `java.util.Arrays#asList()` - из библиотеки Java

Comment: С инт срабатывает автобоксинг. Если с чарами сделать так Arrays.asList('c','d'), то сработает тоже.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Java 8 можно так

```
List<Character> chars = string.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: А без стримов никак?
(И со стримами нормально, но вдруг есть еще способы)

Comment: В Java 8 метода chars() не было. Это в Java 9.

Comment: @notaProgrammer, не правда, у меня `java version "1.8.0_181"
`

Comment: @notaProgrammer [документация](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#chars--) с вами не согласна

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Character> chars = new ArrayList<>();
for (char c : string.toCharArray()) {
    chars.add(c);
}
```